# NumberOfMessagesSent and NumberOfMessagesReceived amazon sqs whith node

Tags: node.js, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to get the total number of messages from a queue but the availables attributes are this

```
var params = {
  QueueUrl: 'STRING_VALUE', // required
  AttributeNames: [
    'Policy | VisibilityTimeout | MaximumMessageSize | MessageRetentionPeriod | ApproximateNumberOfMessages | ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible | CreatedTimestamp | LastModifiedTimestamp | QueueArn | ApproximateNumberOfMessagesDelayed | DelaySeconds | ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds | RedrivePolicy',
    // ... more items ...
  ]
};
sqs.getQueueAttributes(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

how can I get NumberOfMessagesSent and NumberOfMessagesReceived?

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to get "number of messages sent" not "number of messages received" because those are counts which happen over a timespan which you aren't providing.

SQS does however log metrics to cloudwatch and you can get graphs and set alerts on them.  Both of these metrics are available to you.   Here is a link to the documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/MonitorSQSwithCloudWatch.html